# Does Linux support audio output via USB?

Tags: linux, usb, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

Several small integrated amplifiers exist with a USB input line. 
The ones I have seen so far ship with Windows and OS X drivers.

Does Linux support audio output via USB out-of-the-box?

**Update**

It is a [Teac A-H01](http://www.teac.eu/hifi-audio/reference-series/h-01/a-h01/) I have in mind, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Not the same, but I have a Logitech USB G35 headset that works well in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the device reports itself as a USB Audio device the ALSA driver will support it, although the exact definition of "support" may vary for more complex devices.

Comment: I have updated the post which the device model, but all I really want from it is that it outputs the stereo sound.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. (However not all USB audio cards are compatible with all systems.)

I'm not sure what you mean by "out of the box" (which box, the computer or the USB sound card...)

According to [Linux-Usb.org](http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x319.html) as long as "You need to turn on the Sound card support kernel option, which is in the Sound section. You will then be able to turn on the USB Audio support option in the normal USB section."

Comment: That is great, so I suppose as long as I use a vendor kernel this should be configured for me. I have updated the post with the amplifier model, just in case someone knows this exact model.